# Imprimir qual(ais) palavras se repetem em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, como eu poderia fazer para saber qual ou quais palavras se repetiram?

Por exemplo, eu tenho um arquivo.txt, no qual quando eu abro ele como .read() e ele me retorna isso...

```
Alface, Alecrim, Capim, Limão, Alface, Azeitona, Alface
```

E eu quero saber quantas palavras começam com a letra A, então eu fiz

```
import re
arq = open('arquivo.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8")
manipulado = arq.read()
print(manipulado)
r1 = re.findall(r'A\w+', manipulado)
print(r1)
```

Ele me retorna

```
[Alface, Alecrim, Alface, Azeitona, Alface]
```

Como eu poderia fazer para imprimir

```
[Alface, Alecrim, Alface, Azeitona, Alface]
Alface: 3
```

Comment: A minha lista retorna strings, nessa outra pergunta a lista é com inteiros, seria o mesmo processo?

Comment: Sim, é a mesma coisa. Talvez tenha que fazer uma pequena modificação ou outra mas deve ser simples. Teste o código para ver. _Cheguei nessa pergunta com uma breve pesquisa no site, mas se você fizer uma pesquisa melhor por aqui provavelmente vai encontrar uma ainda mais parecida._ :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798674/python-duplicate-words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- É aconselhável usar a instrução `with` pra carregar arquivos
- As listas possuem o método `count` que faze exatamente o que você precisa

O código ficaria assim:

```py
import re

with open('arquivo.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    conteudo = f.read()

print(conteudo)

r1 = re.findall(r'A\w+', conteudo)
qtde_alface = r1.count('Alface')
print('Alface:', qtde_alface)
```

Documentação relevante:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

---

Em comentário você escreveu:

> Mas e se eu não souber quais repetem, esse foi um exemplo que eu criei mas e se fosse um texto muito extenso, teria como fazer isso de forma automática ou seria algo extremamente complexo?

Não está bem claro o que você quer fazer. Se a intenção é contar todas as palavras que começam com a letra "a", você pode usar a classe `Counter`.

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('arquivo.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    conteudo = f.read()

print(conteudo)

r1 = re.findall(r'A\w+', conteudo)

contador = Counter(r1)

for palavra, quantidade in contador.items():
    print(f'A palavra {palavra} se repete {quantidade} vez(es)')
```

Se você quiser descobrir somente qual é a palavra que mais se repete com a letra "a", use o método `most_common` do `Counter`.

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('arquivo.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    conteudo = f.read()

print(conteudo)

r1 = re.findall(r'A\w+', conteudo)

contador = Counter(r1)

palavra, quantidade = contador.most_common(1)[0]

print(f'A palavra que mais se repete é {palavra}, aparecendo {quantidade} vez(es)')
```

Comment: Mas e se eu não souber quais repetem, esse foi um exemplo que eu criei mas e se fosse um texto muito extenso, teria como fazer isso de forma automática ou seria algo extremamente complexo?

Comment: @LexusRX Editei a resposta com mais informações. Não está muito claro o que exatamente você quer fazer. Tente definir com precisão qual é o objetivo do seu programa.

Comment: Obrigado, estou apenas estudando não é um programa prático. Mas uma dúvida apenas, qual o significado do 1 e 0 em "contador.most_common(1)[0]" e do "f" dentro do último print.

Comment: @LexusRX O método `most_common` recebe por parâmetro a quantidade de palavras que vai retornar. Como eu só queria a mais repetida, passei 1 como parâmetro (se eu quisesse as 3 que mais se repetem, passaria 3). Esse método devolve uma lista, que nesse caso só tem um elemento (pois eu pedi apenas 1), daí eu usei o `[0]` pra pegar o primeiro elemento dessa lista (que, como eu disse, só tem um elemento).

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado, vou estudar esses métodos agora.

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi direito oque você quer é ler arquivo.txt e quer contar quantas palavras começaram com a letra 'a'.

Para isso você poderia usar o método .readlines(), igualar a uma variavel e para cada linha que for lida, você utiliza uma das funções das strings que é ser usada como uma lista

Acho que com o código fica mais fácil de entender:

```
contador = 0 #Variável que utilizaremos para contar
with open('arquivo.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
    for line in lines: 
        if line[0].lower() in 'a': 
            #funcionalidade de lista em strings
            contador += 1
print(contado)
```

Não se esqueça de colocar o encoding quando for abrir o arquivo, pois senão ele usará o enconding padrão e com está a acentuação é diferente

Caso queira contar também as frases que incluirem acentos, podes instalar a biblioteca unidecode

```
 from unidecode import unidecode

 lines=[]
 contador = 0
 with open('arquivo.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for c in f.readlines():
       lines.append(unidecode(c)) 
    for line in lines:
       if line[0].lower() in 'a':
           contador += 1
 print(contador)
```

Consegui fazer assim pois não conheço método para tirar acentuação de lista e este foi o modo mais fácil para mim

Se estiver com dificuldades de instalar a biblioteca unidecode, vá no terminal, acesse o diretório scripts (interpretador da sua IDE) e coloque:
pip install unidecode

Por exemplo com o pycharm no windows:

```
cd C:\Users\<nome do usuário que está usando>\<pasta onde guarda seus programas>\venv\Scripts && pip install unidecode
```

Agora se você desejas mostrar a palavra em si que se repetiu, podes fazer assim:

```
   repetido =[]
   with open('arquivo.txt','r') as final:
      ultimo = final.readlines()
      if ultimo[len(ultimo)-1] != '.':
      with open('bans.txt','a') as u:
         u.write('\n.')

   with open('arquivo.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
      lines = f.readlines()

   p = []
   for line in lines:
      t = 0
      repetido = [f'{line}']
      for c,v in enumerate(lines):
         repetido[0]
         if v == repetido[0]:
            if t!=0:
               if c not in p:
                  print(v,c)
                  p.append(c)
            else:
               t+=1
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Caso tenha alguma dúvida sobre uma função ou não entendeu o meu procedimento, apenas mande um comentário e tentarei respondê-lo o mais rápido póssivel

OBS:Este programa diferencia palavras com letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, com acentuação ou sem e também funciona melhor sendo tudo em tópicos